# How to show and close form on click of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a div is clicked I want to show a form, as done on this [page](http://kopatheme.com/demo/great-blog-free-web-template/). This is what I have tried ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aarrLL02/6/)):

```
$(document).on("click","#tawkchat-minified-container",function() {
    var htmldynamic = '  <form id="test" action="test.php">\
<div>\
  Test: <input name="blah" value="test" type="text">\
</div>\
</form>'
    $("#maximizeChat").html(htmldynamic);
});
```

I don't know if this is the right way to do it. Is there a better approach?

Comment: yout html should be imporived

Answer (score 3):

Adding large chunks of HTML as JavaScript variables is not good practice. It is easy to make errors in the HTML as you have to read it awkwardly embedded in the JS.

A better approach is to include the HTML code with the rest of your markup, but use CSS to hide it. Then you can just show it using JavaScript when it is pressed.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="my-form-container">
  <div id="my-form-header">My form</div>
  <form id="my-form" action="test.php">
    <div>
      Test: <input name="blah" value="test" type="text">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#my-form { 
  display: none; /* This will hide the form. */
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
//When the container is clicked...
$("#my-form-container").click(function() {
  //...show the form.
  $("#my-form").show();
});
```

Comment: I have tried with your code , but i am not getting form , could you please tell me if the id is correct in the click event ??

Comment: The id can be anything, as long as you use the same id in the HTML and the JavaScript (but with the added `#`). I called it `my-form-container`, you  can (and should) call it something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach will definitely solve your problem

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tawkchat-minified-agent-container").click(function()
      var hlink = $("#test").val();
      $("#test").click(function(){
        $(".form").show()
      });
  });
});
```